# RestKit - Relashionship Mapping with CoreData - Response Error

Tags: objective-c, core-data, restkit

I have a Guest entity and inside guest is a City entity. I've setup a relashionship in CoreData and RestKit using the RKRelationshipMapping.

I've mapped a single entity correctly, but when I use RKRelationshipMapping to add a City Entity it seems to generate a this error while calling the following method with the @"cityId" property:

```
-[RKPropertyInspector classForPropertyNamed:ofEntity:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

My mapping code:

```
RKObjectManager *objectManager   = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.serverBaseAddress]];
    objectManager.managedObjectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore];

    [RKObjectManager setSharedManager:objectManager];

    RKEntityMapping *cityEMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:self.cityEntityName inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];
    [cityEMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                        @"id"    : @"cityId",
                                                        @"name"  : @"name"
                                                        }];

    RKEntityMapping *guestEMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:self.entityName inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];
    [guestEMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                        @"name"     : @"name",
                                                        @"photo"    : @"photo",
                                                        @"comment"  : @"comment",
                                                        @"id"       : @"guestId",
                                                        @"date"     : @"date"
                                                        }];

    [guestEMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"city"
                                                                                  toKeyPath:@"city"
                                                                                withMapping:cityEMapping]];

    guestEMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"guestId" ];

    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:guestEMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:self.postGetAddress keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
    [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
```

And where the app stops: (propertyClass receiving 0x00 in propertyClass = [[RKPropertyInspector sharedInspector]...)

```
- (Class)classForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
{
    NSArray *components = [keyPath componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    Class propertyClass = self.objectClass;
    for (NSString *property in components) {
        propertyClass = [[RKPropertyInspector sharedInspector] classForPropertyNamed:property ofClass:propertyClass isPrimitive:nil]; 
        if (! propertyClass) propertyClass = [[RKPropertyInspector sharedInspector] classForPropertyNamed:property ofEntity:self.entity];
        if (! propertyClass) break;
    }

    return propertyClass;
}
```

And here is the json:

```
    [{"id":"3","name":"Convidado3","city":{"id":"2","name":"SÃ£o Paulo"},"date":"Data2","comment":"comentario3","photo":":P"},
     {"id":"2","name":"Convidado2","city":{"id":"1","name":"Rio de Janeiro"},"date":"Data2","comment":"comentario2","photo":":|"},
     {"id":"1","name":"Convidado1","city":{"id":"1","name":"Rio de Janeiro"},"date":"Data1","comment":"comentario1","photo":":)"},
     {"id":"5","name":"Convidado5","city":{"id":"4","name":"VitÃ³ria"},"date":"Data4","comment":"comentario5","photo":":K"},
     {"id":"4","name":"Convidado4","city":{"id":"3","name":"Belo Horizonte"},"date":"Data3","comment":"comentario4","photo":";)"}]
```

The entity Guest has a relationship called city which is connected to the City Entity through a relationship called guests in the following manner:
Guest.....City
city<--->>guests

If I simply remove the relationship it works ok, without city sub object... 
Any help or suggestions appreciated...

Comment: Don't you miss an identification attribute in your city mapping ?

Comment: Have you set the linker values properly?

Comment: Ok, I've added the identification attribute in the city mapping (after `RKEntityMapping *cityEMapping`), `cityEMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"cityId" ];` now the error is elsewhere: `static NSArray *RKArrayOfAttributesForEntityFromAttributesOrNames(NSEntityDescription *entity, NSArray *attributesOrNames)`... I can see the guest entity and it has a city property with a NSRelationshipDescription as value. But still when the code runs `NSAttributeDescription *attribute = [[entity attributesByName] valueForKey:attributeOrName];` attribute receives nil... and this raises a `NSException`

Comment: Wain, what do you mean by linker values? Just to help clarify how I reached the current code, I've been following the [link](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping), Relationships section code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem:

After going through all the steps in debug, I changed the following line

**From:**

```
RKEntityMapping *cityEMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:self.cityEntityName inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];
```

**To:**

```
RKEntityMapping *cityEMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"City" inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];
```

And it worked!

I don't understand the problem, as I checked the value of *self.cityEntityName* during debug and it is *@"City"*, so technically it should work. As for the line:

```
RKEntityMapping *guestEMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:self.entityName inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];
```

works just fine... without any changes, I don't know what to say. Thanks for the suggestions.